# Rectangle rotate once at MouseRightButtonDown

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, rectangles

I need your help with this issue i have been struggling for the past day. I want to rotate a rectangle at an angle of 30° everytime i press the rightClickButton.

It works fine when i click once on the rightClickButton.But when i want to  right click again it doesnt rotate anymore.

It's the same behavior with MouseButtonEventHandler or without.

Can you tell me what's wrong with my fudging code

Thanks in advance.

```
   private void Rectangle_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
          {
                MouseButtonEventHandlerRightClick(sender, e);
          }
   private void MouseButtonEventHandlerRightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
        element = (Rectangle)sender;
     if (Mouse.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
         {
                Console.WriteLine("has cliqued right");
                anc_width = element.Width;
                anc_height = element.Height;
                i += 1;
                Console.WriteLine("before transform of guantanamera");
               double angle = 30;
               RotateTransform rotateTransform2 = new RotateTransform(angle);
              rotateTransform2.CenterX = element.Width / 2;
              rotateTransform2.CenterY = element.Height / 2;
            // Console.WriteLine(element.Width / 2 + " toto "+ element.Height/2);
             element.RenderTransform = rotateTransform2;
            /* Canvas.SetLeft(element, Canvas.GetLeft(element)+40);
            Canvas.SetTop(element, Canvas.GetTop(element));*/
      }
   else
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Releasing Element");
         element = null;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always setting the same angle of 30°, while you should actually add 30° to the current value of the `Angle` property of an already existing RotateTransform.

Besides that, it's also unnecessary to set the transform's center. Set the element's `RenderTransformOrigin` property instead.

```
var rotateTransform = element.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;

if (rotateTransform == null)
{
    rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
    element.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
    element.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
}

rotateTransform.Angle += 30;
```

You may also consider setting the transform in advance in XAML:

```
<Rectangle RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" ...>
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: Thanks it works when i increase the angle at each click